# Scheme - nested definition confusion

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm currently stuck on a problem creating func and am a beginner at Scheme. In order to achieve such a result, will I have to define double inside func?

```
(func double 3 '(3 5 1))
```

would return (24 40 8) because each element is doubled 3 times.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer?

Answer (score 2):

No, `double` needs to be outside `func` because it will be passed as a parameter (bound to `f`) to `func`:

```
(define (double n) (* 2 n))

(define (times f e t)
  (if (= t 0)
      e
      (times f (f e) (- t 1))))

(define (func f t lst)
  (map (lambda (e) (times f e t)) lst))
```

then

```
> (func double 3 '(3 5 1)) 
'(24 40 8)
```

OTOH, in this case `times` could be defined inside `func`, but it's a reusable procedure so I'd leave it outside.

Comment: You could pass the symbol `'double` in as a message, and have an internal dispatch and definition especially if func were to keep any sort of internal state.

Comment: I don't see the point of an internal dispatch, and I'm sorry I don't see the need to do so in if `func` has some kind of state. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you keep an internal dispatch table or alist you can avoid namespace conflicts, yet keep a way to extend available functionality, say a function to double strings, or a way to apply any of the internal functions to trees and vectors. Maybe you want to increment a counter every time a certain message is passed in.

Comment: Yes, probably not what's needed here, but message passing can be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, here's one way you can implement `func`:

```
(define (func f n lst)
  (do ((n n (sub1 n))
       (lst lst (map f lst)))
      ((zero? n) lst)))
```

Example usage:

```
> (func (lambda (x) (* x 2)) 3 '(3 5 1))
=> (24 40 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#lang racket

(define (repeat f x n)
  (cond [(= n 0) x]
        [else    (f (repeat f x (- n 1)))]))

(define (func f n xs)
  (map (λ(x) (repeat f x n)) xs))

(define (double x) 
  (* 2 x))

(func double 3 '(3 5 1))
```

Comment: Interesting to compare and contrast your approach to mine: you map once with a function that does the repeating, whereas I map multiple times with the original function. :-)

Comment: Nice observation. Rereading the OP's question, I think we both forgot to answer how to define double :-) We focused on func.

Comment: Well, if you read the question more literally, the OP wanted to define `func`, and wanted to know if `double` had to be defined within. The answer, of course, is no, as both answers demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:

```
(define (cmap fun arg1 lst)
  (map (lambda (x) (fun arg1 x)) lst))
```

But really you want to do this `(cmap list 1 (get-some-calc x) (get-list))` but it's very difficult to make it take any curried argument and perhaps you want more than one list. You do it like this:

```
(let ((cval (get-come-calc x)))
  (map (lambda (x) (list 1 cval x)) (get-list)))
```